# asp.net - SelectItemTemplate doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, xhtml

I have two tables. First works fine - if button ID="Button1" CommandName="Select"  pressed selected item turns red. But second table doesn't do the same if I pressed it's own button ID="Button2" CommandName="Select".

first table listView ID="ListViewGrSDtudents"

second table listView ID="ListViewGroups"

Does somebody now what why it doesn't work?

It's my .aspx code:

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <!-- Таблица групп -->
        <div>
            <asp:ListView ID="ListViewGroups"
                runat="server"
                ItemType="BD_Class_Library.studentGroup"
                DataKeyNames="groupId"
                SelectMethod="GetStudGroups"
                InsertMethod="InsertStudGroup"
                UpdateMethod="UpdateGroup"
                DeleteMethod="DeleteGroup"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListViewGroups_SelectedIndexChanged">

                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="background-color: yellowgreen">
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="groupName" runat="server" value="<%# BindItem.groupName %>" /></td>

                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" Width="100%" CommandName="Insert" runat="server" Text="Вставить" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </InsertItemTemplate>

                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="background-color: yellow">
                        <td><%# Item.groupId %></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="groupName" runat="server" value="<%# BindItem.groupName %>" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button CommandName="Update" runat="server" Text="Сохранить" />
                            <asp:Button CommandName="Cancel" runat="server" Text="Отмена" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </EditItemTemplate>


                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <table border="1">
                        <tr style="background-color: darkgray">
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Группа</th>

                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
                    </table>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <SelectedItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="background-color: red">
                        <td><%# Item.groupId %></td>
                        <td><%# Item.groupName %></td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button CommandName="Edit" runat="server" Text="Изменить" />
                            <asp:Button CommandName="Delete" runat="server" Text="Удалить" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </SelectedItemTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="background-color: grey">
                        <td><%# Item.groupId %></td>
                        <td><%# Item.groupName %></td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button CommandName="Select" runat="server" Text="Выбрать" />
                            <asp:Button CommandName="Edit" runat="server" Text="Изменить" />
                            <asp:Button CommandName="Delete" runat="server" Text="Удалить" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>


            </asp:ListView>
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:ListView
                ID="ListViewGrSDtudents"
                runat="server"
                ItemType="BD_Class_Library.student"
                DataKeyNames="studId"
                OnSelectedIndexChanging="ListViewGrSDtudents_SelectedIndexChanging"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListViewGrSDtudents_SelectedIndexChanged">

                <SelectedItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="background-color: red">
                        <td><%# Item.studId %></td>
                        <td><%# Item.studFam %></td>
                        <td><%# Item.studName %></td>
                        <td><%# Item.studOtc %></td>
                        <td><%# Item.studBiletNum %></td>
                    </tr>
                </SelectedItemTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="background-color: grey">
                        <td><%# Item.studId %></td>
                        <td><%# Item.studFam %></td>
                        <td><%# Item.studName %></td>
                        <td><%# Item.studOtc %></td>
                        <td><%# Item.studBiletNum %></td>
                        <td><asp:Button ID="Button2" CommandName="Select" runat="server" Text="Выбрать" /></td>


                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <table border="1" style="width: 60%">
                        <tr id="groupPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
                        <tr style="background-color: aqua">
                            <th>ID студента</th>
                            <th>Фамилия</th>
                            <th>Имя</th>
                            <th>Отчество</th>
                            <th>Студ. билет</th>

                        </tr>
                        <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" itemplaceholderid="itemPlaceholderStudent"></tr>
                    </table>
                </LayoutTemplate>

                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <table border="1" style="width: 60%">
                        <tr style="background-color: aqua">
                            <th>ID студента</th>
                            <th>Фамилия</th>
                            <th>Имя</th>
                            <th>Отчество</th>
                            <th>Студ. билет</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color: grey">
                            <td colspan="5" style="text-align: center">В данной группе нет студентов</<td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
        </div>


    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

event - ListViewGrSDtudents_SelectedIndexChanged code:

```
    protected void ListViewGrSDtudents_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int selStudent = (int)ListViewGrSDtudents.SelectedDataKey.Value;
        Session["SelectedStudent"] = selStudent;
        Session["SelectedStudentIndex"] = ListViewGrSDtudents.SelectedIndex;
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");

    }
```

[Description Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35OxL.png)

[Description Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rclal.png)

Comment: `itemplaceholderid` property belongs to `ListView` not itempaceholder itself.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev, Thanks for the answer, but don't get how can I fix it?

Comment: just remove `itemplaceholderid="itemPlaceholderStudent"`

Comment: @AlexKudryashev, button doesn't work anyway :(

Comment: Check your  `OnSelectedIndexChanging` and `OnSelectedIndexChanged` handlers.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev, I add ListViewGrSDtudents_SelectedIndexChanged code and ListViewGrSDtudents_SelectedIndexChanging have nothing in it yet

Comment: Your `Response.Redirect` reloads the page in its original state. Should be `ListViewGrSDtudents.DataBind()`

Comment: @AlexKudryashev, really sorry, but replacing Response.Redirect with ListViewGrSDtudents.DataBind() doesn't change anything